# Edit bot behavior Telegram

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I created a bot on Telegram with BotFather.

Now I want to add it to a conversation, so it needs of some skills like :

- Ban/timeout who spam messages (and gives allerts to stop spam).
- Ban who uses bad languages (so a word check).

And others...

I would like to avoid coding, are there some free tools to do it quick or I have to code?
I'm looking also for suggestions so I'm open to any idea...

Answer (score 1):

There are few conversational platforms out there which support the creation of a chatbot without coding skills. A popular option is [DialogFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs) which can integrate with [Telegram](https://chatbotsjournal.com/how-to-integrate-your-dialogflow-chatbot-with-telegram-without-coding-7c8a51d3417e).

In order to add the specific behaviour you mention (ban bad language, spam) you will need to use some coding. You can design the conversation with DialogFlow and then define a webhook (a web service to simplify the scenario) which can process the Intent identified by DialogFlow.

For example you could get the message typed by the user and, using some coding or an existing application, determine if it contains bad language.

Comment: Are there other ways? Because Google doesn't accept my credit card so I can't sign in to use DialogFlow

Comment: You shouldnt need credit card with DialogFlow. Other options you can start from here https://influencermarketinghub.com/ai-chatbot-platforms/

Comment: Yes I solved it now, thanks